# Why some part of android hint stay like shadow after typing?

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext

I have problem  with my login layout. here is default:

[image]

But when user start typing. some problem is happen. hint text isn't completely clear.

[image]

here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/login_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_box"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_usernamebox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_usernametextbox"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text=" Username:  "
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login_usernameedittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="Please enter username."
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

what is my mistake? anyone can help me?

Comment: sounds like your font-family is making this issue, try remove font-family and check if it works good, and then find a solution to apply font-family properly / dynamically

Answer (score 0):

i think your error in `android:fontFamily="sans-serif"` 
to solve it , Remove this line and Run app , if it solve you can set font by this steps

set your file font `.ttf` in this path assets/fonts/

[image: Path]

**create Folders if not found it**

in your **.java** file set it in your code

```
Typeface Font =     Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/DroidSansArabic.ttf");
```

and set it in any text in this file **.java**

Exmple :

```
TextView   Test=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
Test.setTypeface(Font);
```